# If $X$ is ill-defined, is $(\forall x\in X)(f(x)=y)$ vacuously true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets with arbitrary elements $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be some function. Then, consider a statement of the form
\begin{gather}
    (\forall x\in X)(f(x)=y)
\end{gather}
If $X=\emptyset$, then the statement above is vacuously true. Suppose however that the set $X$ is ill-defined rather than empty. **Would then the above statement still be vacuously true?**

**EDIT** Following the comments, I clarify that "by ill-defined" I mean that the set $X$ does not exist. Let me provide an informal example. Consider the statement:

*All the phones in the classroom are turned off.*

If there are no phones in the classroom, then the statement is vacuously true. **However, if there is no classroom, is the above statement still vacuously true?**

I am inclined to think it is not, because as said in the comments, the antecedent is not *unsatisfiable*.

Comment: What do you mean by ill-defined. If you mean that it doesn't have a meaningful definition, then the statement would inherit that and so would have no meaningful truth value.

Comment: I think this is too vague.  What does "ill-defined" mean here?  If I write, "Let $X=\{3,5,7,\cdots\}$" one could well complain that it is ill-defined.  Do I mean the odd natural numbers $>1$?  Do I mean the primes?  Something else?  But we are at least sure that $X$ contains $3,5$ and $7$.

Comment: Can you give an example of an ill-defined set? I think that your example is simply an ill-defined logical statement.

Comment: A _vacuous_ truth is one with _unsatisfiable_ antecedent, but $x\in X$ is only _unsatisfiable_ if $X=\emptyset$. See also @lulu's example of when an ill-defined set is clearly non-empty.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I am sorry for my bad choice of words. What I mean by "ill-defined" is that the set X does not exist.

Comment: The statement $\forall x\in X\dots$ only makes sense for objects $X$ for which $x\in X$ makes sense. In standard set theory, this means $X$ being a set, but in other set theories, this would be when $X$ is a class. An ill-defined set is not a set and not a class.

Comment: $X$ not existing means that $X$ is not a set.

Comment: The statement still doesn't make sense even after the edit. How could $x \in X$ if $X$ doesn't exist? That would mean $f(x) = y$ is meaningless.

Comment: However, if you have some condition which is not true for any set, $P(X),$ then the statement:  $$\forall X\left(P(X)\implies \forall x\in X(Q(x))\right)$$ is true for any statement $Q.$ But that's because a false statement implies anything. So you also get: $$\forall X\left(P(X)\implies\lnot \forall x\in X(Q(x))\right)$$

For example, if $P(X)$ is $X=\emptyset\land \exists x(x\in X).$